# How to go about organizing 3 elements in a navigation menu button?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical navigation menu, of which each button contains at max 3 elements.

The first is a *descriptive glyph icon*, the 2nd is the *text* and the 3rd is an *optionally shown icon* that indicates that this is the current selecton.

Here is what the `li` element has:

```
<a href="index.php">
  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-home"></i>
  <span class="navlink">
  home page
  </span>
  <div id="curpg-container">
  <i class="fa"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

I want to achive two things:

1. Make the first icon take up the whole height of the button (vertically allign it to the center) (cause if the text is large, it collapses below the icon)
2. Make the third icon, vertically alligned to the center and also horizontally aligned to the right of the button.

(**image 1 has correct look, image 2 is erroneous**)
[image: normal]
[image: search]

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/P4H9P/) is how the menu is now.

Comment: @gla3dr Hmm that worked fine for the paperclip but changed the center vertical alignment of the glyph :/ Tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most optimal approach is to use pseudo-elements - `:before` and `:after` - to avoid cluttering HTML code with unnecessary markup.

Here's an example of how this can be done with the help of background image placement: http://jsfiddle.net/7E7ph/.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul > li + li {
    border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    font: normal 14px/1 Sans-Serif;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative
}

ul > li > a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    left: 4px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16) no-repeat;
}

ul > li:last-child > a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    right: 6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/12x12) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure... but maybe {word-break:break-all;} could help you.
Also, you can surround the "inline" with just use span element (natural inline).
Try this:

CSS:

```
.current-page-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 7em;
    top: -1.2em;
    height: .94em;
    width: 5rem;
}

.icon{
    width:10%;
    background-color:#123456;
}
.text{
    width:90%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">
                        <i>Icon2</i>
                        <span class="navlink">Home</span>
                        <div class="current-page-container">
                            <span class="icon"><i>o</i></span>
                            <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Tell me if this is what you want. :)